# scrollbar in IE6

Tags: css, joomla, mootools, internet-explorer-6

Today, I tried to browse my Joomla website in an ancient browser, IE6.

All elements looked fine, but I saw a long horizontal scrollbar in pages with SqueezeBox (Joomla modal box) enabled.

To find the problem, I edited template and remove all code beside `<body>` tag. And tried again, I saw blank page, with a close button and a long scrollbar. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xac1K.png))

`<body>` contents:

```
<div tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 65555; opacity: 0;" aria-hidden="true" id="sbox-overlay"></div>
<div class="shadow" style="z-index: 65557;" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" id="sbox-window">
    <div style="opacity: 0;" id="sbox-content"></div>
    <a aria-controls="sbox-window" role="button" href="#" id="sbox-btn-close"></a>
</div>
```

`<body>` styles:

```
color: #000000;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
```

modal.css (SqueezeBox stylesheet):

```
/**
 * SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox
 *
 * Allows to open various content as modal,
 * centered and animated box.
 *
 * @version     1.3
 *
 * @license     MIT-style license
 * @author      Harald Kirschner <mail [at] digitarald.de>
 * @author      Rouven Weßling <me [at] rouvenwessling.de>
 * @copyright   Author
 */

#sbox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#sbox-window {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px;
    /* invalid values, but looks smoother! */
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#sbox-window[aria-hidden=true],
#sbox-overlay[aria-hidden=true] {
    display: none;
}

#sbox-btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    right: -15px;
    top: -15px;
    background: url(../images/modal/closebox.png) no-repeat center;
    border: none;
}

.sbox-loading #sbox-content {
    background-image: url(../images/modal/spinner.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#sbox-content {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.sbox-content-image#sbox-content {
    overflow: visible;
}

#sbox-image {
    display: block;
}

.sbox-content-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sbox-content-iframe#sbox-content {
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Hides scrollbars */
.body-overlayed {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Hides flash (Firefox problem) and selects (IE) */
.body-overlayed embed, .body-overlayed object, .body-overlayed select {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#sbox-window embed, #sbox-window object, #sbox-window select {
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Shadows */
#sbox-window.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.sbox-bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33px;
    height: 40px;
}

.sbox-bg-n {
    left: 0;
    top: -40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_n.png) repeat-x;
}
.sbox-bg-ne {
    right: -33px;
    top: -40px;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_ne.png) no-repeat;
}
.sbox-bg-e {
    right: -33px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_e.png) repeat-y;
}
.sbox-bg-se {
    right: -33px;
    bottom: -40px;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_se.png) no-repeat;
}
.sbox-bg-s {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_s.png) repeat-x;
}
.sbox-bg-sw {
    left: -33px;
    bottom: -40px;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_sw.png) no-repeat;
}
.sbox-bg-w {
    left: -33px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_w.png) repeat-y;
}
.sbox-bg-nw {
    left: -33px;
    top: -40px;
    background: url(../images/modal/bg_nw.png) no-repeat;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .body-overlayed {
    overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong is IE6 :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant: :((((.... it's one of my clients...

Comment: @kikio With such a client it's probably better to render the web pages as images or pdf, when they're accessed by IE6. About the only way you get to keep both your sanity and your client.

Comment: Its just a shot in dark, but did you try position relative on body?

Answer (score 1):

if your client is still using IE6, they must surely be used to seeing websites that look broken? Just how bad is this scrollbar? Does it affect usability? If the user can still use the site, I would suggest telling them to live with it, at least until they upgrade their browser.

If they really can't upgrade and insist on you fixing the problem, you could try using `overflow:hidden` to prevent the scrollbar from showing up.

But beware that there might be other issues with IE6 on your site. In fact, there almost certainly are. If the user keeps insisting on you fixing up the site just for them, you might find yourself doing quite a bit of work just for one user. You should ask yourself *now* just how much this customer is worth to you, and how much time you're willing to spend supporting them.

Comment: you're right. but someone hired me to solve his (now my!) bugs in IE6. So I have to solve all problems... not only hide them.

Comment: hmm, good luck with that. I hope he's paying you well for this work. I can't see anything obvious in the CSS code you've provided. You're going to need some sort of debugging tools for this, and sadly IE6 doesn't have any decent debugging tools. The best I know is either the DebugBar tool that comes with IETester, or FirebugLite. Neither of these is anywhere like as good as the kind of dev tools you get in modern browsers, but they may help. In the meanwhile, `overflow:hidden` may be the answer to this question, even if it is a bit of a hack, as long as nothing important gets hidden. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code, try this:

```
#sbox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```